# .htaccess doesn't work on custom folders in codeigniter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-ec2

I have my site running in Codeigniter. I have my own folder names custom where I have placed a simple .htaccess which has

```
Deny from all
```

But when i hit www.example.com/custom, it shows all files in browser. However, If I hit www.example.com/system, it says "Directory access is forbidden."

My folder structure is as follows.

```
mysite
mysite/system
mysite/custom
mysite/application
```

....

I have different .htaccess in root file and the redirection works fine.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]  

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/woff
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A0
  <FilesMatch "\.(ico|ICO|pdf|PDF|flv|FLV|jpg|JPG|jpeg|JPEG|png|PNG|gif|GIF|js|JS|css|CSS|swf|SWF)(\.gz)?$">
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
  Header append Cache-Control â€œpublicâ€
  Header unset ETag
  FileETag None
  Header set Expires "Thu, 15 Apr 2025 20:00:00 GMT"
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch â€œ\.(xml|txt|html)$â€>
  ExpiresDefault A7200
  Header append Cache-Control â€œproxy-revalidateâ€
  </FilesMatch>
  <FilesMatch â€œ\.(js|css)$â€>
  ExpiresDefault A259200
  Header append Cache-Control â€œproxy-revalidateâ€
  </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

I have the

```
Deny from all
```

in rest of the sub folders. System and application folders comes with CI. htaccess works fine in this folder. But in my own created folder "custom", htaccess file is not working.

What might be the problem? Why it allows htaccess work in the default folders and why it is not working in the user created folders

Note: I have same setting working in my nginx server. I have a different site Im uploading now. It is not working on the apache folder.

Comment: What is location of this .htaccess? Are you sure this .htaccess is enabled?

Comment: I have .htaccess in root as well as in the subfolder. .htaccess in root is working fine. I have a sub folder system, custom. .htaccess works in system folder and not in the custom folder.

Comment: So `Deny from all` is in some folder not in root? Does `Deny from all` work from root .htaccess?

Comment: Yes. .htaccess works fine from root folder

Comment: OK, If you want people to help you, you need to provide many more details in question since I cannot keep asking many questions in comments section. What URL did you enter in browser, where is this .htaccess located etc

Comment: Sorry for that anubhava.. I have explained better in my question.

Comment: ok can you also show full content of root .htaccess?

Comment: Anubhava, thanks for helping me in this. i have added more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your `/custom/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

Deny from all
```

Comment: No effects Anubhava.. It is still the same.

Comment: I have tested exactly same setup and getting 403 forbidden error when I visit URL: `http://localhost/custom/` where `/custom/` is a real directory.

Answer (score 0):

Delete your browser cache with (CTRL + F5) for WINDOWS or (Command + R) for MACOS and try again, make sure you have (dot) .htaccess and not just htaccess in your mysite/custom folder.